# Search BLOB content in GRAILS

Tags: mysql, grails

I am trying to search blob content and display result in GRAILS. Can anybody please help me to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

What I am trying to do:

1. A 3rd party application is going to upload a file in MySQL as BLOB which is a report in HTML format.
2. In my GRAILS application, I have a search page. User can enter text to search various reports which are stored as BLOB.

What I have achieved till now:

1. I am using searchable plugin in GRAILS to search from MySQL.
2. the plugin works fine, but it returns result for column values but not the content of blob.

Example:

```
| ID | FileName  | FileContent | CreatedBy |
| 1  | abcd.html | (blob)      | abcd      |
| 2  | efgh.html | (blob)      | efgh      |
```

If user searches for *ef*, the page is returned with

```
| 2  | efgh.html | (blob)      | efgh      |
```

But what I want is to search column values plus content of blob.

Comment: I got my reply from http://surendrajnawali.blogspot.in/2013/12/grails-executequery-hql-join-and-return.html

Answer (score 0):

I got mt reply from http://surendrajnawali.blogspot.in/2013/12/grails-executequery-hql-join-and-return.html

It worked the way i wanted.